# Communicating from bash with grunt shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, fifo

I'm tired of the slow startup time of `hadoop fs` just to query HDFS. This isn't a problem with HDFS itself though, because using HDFS file system commands within the Pig "grunt shell" is pretty fast. But it's impractical to always startup the grunt shell when I just want to issue some HDFS commands. So I wrote this script to startup a grunt shell instance in the background for me and keep it open for succeeding calls:

```
#!/bin/bash

in=/tmp/grunt_in
out=/tmp/grunt_out
err=/tmp/grunt_err

if [ ! -p $in ]
then
    mkfifo $in
    mkfifo $out
    ( pig <>$in >$out 2>$err; rm $in $out ) &
    disown
fi

>$err # Truncate errors
echo "fs $*" >$in
echo >$in
echo "-- end" >$in
sed -n '/^grunt> -- end/q;/^grunt>/d;p' $out
cat $err >&2
```

Of course not only the input has to be send to the script, but also the output from the script has to be redirected to my current bash session. I use the `/tmp/grunt_in` and `/tmp/grunt_out` FIFOs here to accomplish that. To figure out when `pig` processed the command I send a `"-- end"` comment and detect that in the `sed` command which is listening on the output to make it quit when encountering the `end` token and only output the relevant part by skipping all `grunt>` prompts.

Note that I have to attach the input FIFO with `<>$in` even though I redirect the output to `$out` to prevent pig from quitting after the first command. I don't know exactly why, but I figured it works this way.

This actually works already quite nice. E.g.

```
$ time hadoop fs -ls
Found 38 items
[ skipped output ]

real    0m1.828s
user    0m3.160s
sys 0m0.137s

$ time dfs -ls

[apollo@dc1-had03-clusterutil01 reporting-APO-5394]$ time dfs -ls
Found 38 items
[ skipped output ]

real    0m0.149s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.006s
```

(I called my script `dfs` here.) There are only two problems left which I can't figure out currently:

1. When I call the script the first time (that is when the fifo `/tmp/grunt_in` isn't existing yet and the pig instance is started in the background) my terminal settings are somehow messed up. I don't get an echo of my input anymore, so I have to type a `reset` blindly to get a sane terminal back. Succeeding calls work fine though.
2. When I try to output file contents on HDFS with `-cat` or `-text` the output gets arbitrarily truncated. E.g.:

   ```
   $ hadoop fs -text some-medium-size.gz|wc -l
   3606
   $ dfs -text some-medium-size.gz|wc -l
   text: Unable to write to output stream.
   9
   ```

   Note the error message `text: Unable to write to output stream.` here which is not coming from `pig` but from the `fs -text` command from `hadoop`. Sometimes it's truncated at the first 9 or 10 lines as here or sometimes somewhere at the middle. It's quite strange. I also tried to send the command manually to `/tmp/grunt_in` and reading `/tmp/grunt_out` with `cat`, with the same result, but this confirms that my parsing with `sed` can't be the issue here. This also doesn't seem to be a problem with big outputs in general, e.g. for long directory listings it just works fine:

   ```
   $ dfs -ls -R|wc -l
   10686
   ```

(Which gives the same result as `hadoop fs -ls -R|wc -l`)

Maybe the last problem is a problem with `hadoop fs -text` and `hadoop fs -cat` itself? Or do I something wrong with my use of named pipes?

Comment: I figured out that the terminal problem occurs after the sed command. By issuing a `stty -a` command I could see that the flags `icanon` and `echo` got disabled but other settings stayed the same. So as a workaround I could put in a `stty sane` command after the `sed` command, but that still doesn't explain why it's happening and why only at the first time. Does `sed` has issues with named pipes?

Comment: I think I found the solution: `pig` expects a terminal and giving him just a "dump" pipe causes all kinds of issues. But the `script` program attaches a `pty` pseudo terminal to a called program. So simply replacing `pig <>$in >$out 2>$err` with `script -q -c pig <>$in >$out 2>$err` seems to solve the issues. . But now I encounter another problem: `script` seems to attach stdout *and* stderr to stdout, so my `2>$err` redirection is useless which is not exactly what I want. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

I now more on less settled on this version:

```
#!/bin/bash

in=/tmp/grunt_in
out=/tmp/grunt_out
err=/tmp/grunt_err

if [ ! -p $in ]
then
    mkfifo $in
    mkfifo $out
    mkfifo $err
    { script -q -c "pig 1>$out 2>$err" <>$in; rm $in $out $err; } &
fi

{
    echo "fs $*"
    echo
    echo "-- end"
} >$in
cat $err >&2 &
catpid=$!
sed -n -u '/^grunt> -- end/q;/^grunt>/d;p' <$out
kill $catpid
```

So I simply redirect stderr inside of the `script` command. I also replaced the round braces with curly braces and removed the `disown` because I didn't see any advantage in doing that. I also replaced `$err` with a FIFO in order to be able to output it early, but that also adds some complications to kill the `cat`.

This works fairly well so far *except* that when I truncate the output by piping through `head` I get a truncated or extra output in the next command. Apparently I need a way to properly flush the named pipes. I would be glad if someone has any hints.

Comment: Use `dd` for blocking out back-pipes - `conv=sync`hronize on `\0NUL`s.

Comment: I might be royally late with this, but thanks! I'm keeping the get and put commands out of it, a bit too dangerous, but for regular operations like ls and stat etc this makes a world of difference!